# getElementById from Object.keys(data)

Tags: javascript, html

I have simple Ajax codes, parsing Json data and filling dynamic divs inside. And I have problem when I want to get dynamically `getElementById`.

My key array returns successfully = ["blue","red","etc"..] 
and I have blue-data, red-data, etc-data div ids.

```
<div id="blue-data">myblue</div>
<div id="red-data">myred</div>
<div id="etc-data">myetc</div>
```

My codes are below:

```
      success: function(data) {
      Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key,index) {


            console.log(document.getElementById(''+key+'-data').innerHTML);


         });

});
```

When I run gives:

> console.log(document.getElementById(''+key+'-data').innerHTML);

Line

```
Error

null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById(''+key+'-data').innerHTML')
```

But in console, output is;

```
myblue
myred
myetc
```

How can I fix this? I want to get with key-data div inside values.

Comment: `Object.keys` is for Objects, not Arrays.

Comment: FYI the `''+` is useless in this context

Comment: @epascarello same error I deleted it's.

Comment: What key is it failing on? console.log(key), my guess is one of them does not exist

Comment: shouldn't be data instead key?, `I mean document.getElementById(''+data+'-data').innerHTML`

Comment: @JuanCaicedo No. the `.forEach()` arguments are `key` and `index`. `data` is what the OP is trying to loop over, but that's an incorrect loop.

Comment: showing in console all of them :(

Comment: All the error message is saying is one of the elements you are trying to find is not there. So what ever the last one is, that element does not exist on the page. `Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key,index) { console.log(key, document.getElementById(key+'-data')); })`

Comment: looks like you have a different array, show the array. myblue, myblue and myetc are different output

Comment: @JuanCaicedo that is the innerHTML.....

Comment: Who will help me lol, maybe this bug ?

Comment: Learn to debug @SwiftDeveloper

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper You need to learn a bit more about your own code. My answer below is the answer. You just need to understand how to apply it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus yes dude, but my codes returns json data and I get this with Object.keys and when I change your codes gives errors

Comment: Show us the data that is returned. We're not fortune tellers!

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper THE PROBLEM IS THE ELEMENT DOES NOT EXIST FOR ONE OF THE INDEXES, figure out why..... The console.log statement will show you what one fails. So the log is going to be `"myblue" <elem>"` for the good ones and `"theissue" null` for the bad one

Comment: @ScottMarcus yes thanks guys that codes works!

Comment: HOW does it work.... What was wrong?

Comment: @epascarello lol .

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper What is funny? What was your mistake so people can learn.

Comment: code learning is funny. if you don't funny , you don't learn :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your returned data is an Array, as you say, then [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is not what you should use as it is for iterating over the properties (keys) of Objects. If you just have an Array, just loop over it directly:

```js
// This is just simulating the result of your `success` handler's argument:
let data= ["blue","red","etc"];

// This would be INSIDE of your success callback function
data.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(document.getElementById(item + '-data').textContent);
});
```

```html
<div id="blue-data">myblue</div>
<div id="red-data">myred</div>
<div id="etc-data">myetc</div>
```

Comment: dude your example working but in my codes says : Can't find variable: result and when I changed result to key, gives ; key.forEach is not a function. (In 'key.forEach(function(key) { console.log(document.getElementById(key + '-data').textContent); })', 'key.forEach' is undefined)

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper I named the variable `result` in my example. Of course you need to modify the name to match your code. In your code, you'd use `data.forEach()`.

Comment: says data.forEach is not a function. (In 'data.forEach(function(item) { console.log(document.getElementById(item + '-data').textContent); })', 'data.forEach' is undefined)

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper **Then you don't actually have the Array that you stated you have in your question.** Add `console.log(data)` as the first line in your `success` handler and tell us what it reports.

Comment: The array he is stating about is Object.keys(data) ..... and if it is looping and erroring out then it is working fine. Issue is one of the keys is not in the DOM and he has to debug that. Literally nothing we can do.

Comment: @ScottMarcus yes your example works but somethings wrongs with my codes. but I will work on. I will return